# SSS CUDA Error/Blender Crash

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I solve all my CUDA out-of-memory errors, and think to understand everyone. But there's one which resist.
What is about SSS? I have two characters. When I try to render them alone, with anything else on my GTX 970: Blender crash!

Anoyone knows anything about this kind on material/shader and CUDA world?

Thanks in advance
Blender 2.78a
Asus GTX 970 CO

Comment: Seems to me the subsurface scattering requires more resources than those on the GPU. Can you render your scene with CPU?

Comment: Hi cegaton, yes I can render without any issue on my CPU. It's a i7 6700 with 32 Gb RAM. It's the way I'm using now to solve the problem...